# BeautifulSoup website scraping - html parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape the data from a website using beautifulsoup4 and retrieve only the information between the html tags to put into an excel doc, currently I am only able to get the entire html data from the page.

```
import sys
import urllib3
import xlsxwriter
import lxml

page = requests.get('genericurlhere.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

f = csv.writer(open('web_scrape.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Item', 'Description'])


heading = soup.find_all("h4", class_="list-group-item-heading")
print(heading)
print('-------------------')
desc = soup.find_all("p", class_='list-group-item-text')
print(desc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `text`:

```
desc = soup.find_all("p", class_='list-group-item-text')
desc = [e.text for e in desc] # only text within tags from the html elements.
print(desc)
```

Note that you can also use `[]` to get attributes to html tags like: `each['id']`